# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Projectfolder.MAINFOLDER'; 'Projectfolder' is not a package

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

Following is my project structure:

```
Projectfolder
    MAINFOLDER
        __init__.py
        SUBFOLDER1
            __init__.py
            SUBFOLDER1programfile1.py
            SUBFOLDER1programfile2.py
            SUBFOLDER1programfile3.py
        SUBFOLDER2
            __init__.py
            SUBFOLDER2programfile1.py
            SUBFOLDER2programfile2.py
            SUBFOLDER2programfile3.py
        SUBFOLDER3
            __init__.py
            SUBFOLDER3programfile1.py
            SUBFOLDER3programfile2.py
            SUBFOLDER3programfile3.py
        SUBFOLDER4
            __init__.py
            SUBFOLDER4programfile1.py
            SUBFOLDER4programfile2.py
            SUBFOLDER4programfile3.py
        SUBFOLDER5
            __init__.py
            SUBFOLDER5programfile1.py
            SUBFOLDER5programfile2.py
            SUBFOLDER5programfile3.py
        programfile1.py
        programfile2.py
        main.py
    __init__.py
    README.txt
```

when I run my main.py file then I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Projectfolder/MAINFOLDER/programfile1.py", line 14, in <module>
    from Projectfolder.MAINFOLDER.SUBFOLDER3.SUBFOLDER3programfile1.py import SUBFOLDER3programfile1
  File ".../Projectfolder\MAINFOLDER\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from Projectfolder.MAINFOLDER.SUBFOLDER5.SUBFOLDER5programfile1.py import SUBFOLDER5programfile1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Projectfolder.MAINFOLDER'; 'Projectfolder' is not a package
```

I had gone through several posts but they did not helped in solving this issue. where am I making the mistake in importing.

Comment: What do you want to import?

Comment: I want to import the classes written in both the files

Comment: I meant what file do you want to import?

Comment: SUBFOLDER5programfile1.py and SUBFOLDER3programfile1.py

Comment: Can you show me your code?